# ubuntu apache2 logfile permission

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm curious.
my apache2 webserver is running as user 'www-data'.
however the directory '/var/log/apache2' doesn't have write access for user 'www-data'

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -al /var/log/apache2
total 10960
drwxr-x---  2 root adm     4096 Sep 30 23:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root    4096 Sep 30 06:25 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root adm  2114548 Sep 30 23:34 access.log
```

How can apache2 create access.log file even if its running as www-data?
am I missing something here?

some advice would be nice.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The log writing is handled by syslog service and syslog is normally a member of adm group on ubuntu machines. Hence the permission is like this.